# How to add re delivery delay in WSO2 Message Broker like ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, wso2, wso2-esb

I have successfully configured the WSO2 Message Broker with my WSO2 ESB. I have also implemented successfully the JMS Transactions. It means that if there is an error in Service Normal Flow, Message will be rolledback.

**Problem:**

Previously i have configured the ActiveMq with my ESB. In that Setup i have a configuration in {ESB_HOME}/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml. This configuration donates the "Re-delivery Delay". This time is used to tell the MessageBroker(ActiveMQ) that when you are attempting to redeliver the message, you have to wait for this time before trying again.

```
<parameter name="redeliveryPolicy.redeliveryDelay" locked="true">1200000</parameter>
```

**WSO2 Message Broker:**

I want to achieve the same result in WSO2 Message Broker. I think it had to do with some configuration in {MB_HOME}/repository/conf/advanced/andes-config.xml. But i am unable to find that particular configuration setting anywhere in Message Broker.

**Note:** I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and WSO2 Message Broker 2.2.0.

**What i want to achieve:**

My goal is that i should be able to tell WSO2 Message Broker like ActiveMQ that you must take this much time before trying to re-deliver the message.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it cannot be done like this in case of WSO2 MB. You have to setup a message store and a message processor guarding on that message store. And when you have a message processor it can be configured with interval and max delivery attempts.

- https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Dead+Letter+Channel
- http://charith.wickramaarachchi.org/2012/05/another-message-redelivery-pattern-with.html
- http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/10/implementing-store-forward-messaging-patterns-wso2esb-part-1
- http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/12/implementing-store-forward-messaging-patterns-wso2esb-part-2/

*(Alternatively, you can setup the maxAckWaitTime, it means it will wait at least 'maxAckWaitTime' seconds between two redelivery attempts)*